# Getting error while reading data from file using structure in C

Tags: c, structure, file-handling, fwrite, fread

I am working on a mini project called ATM as winter assignment. I have done coding for ATM as shown in below code. but I am getting a problem as suppose I have created a database for user and store it in to file but for first user i.e first entry, I can read data easily but for second entry in the file, I can not read the data in the first attempt. In first attempt its shows wrong `Id` and `PIN` but while entering second time all works fine. Same thing happened with third entry in the list i.e third user. For first two attempts it shows wrong `ID` and `PIN` but in third attempts all works fine. As so on for all users i.e forth, fifth etc.

Here is the my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct user
{  
    int id;
    char fname[20],lname[20];
    long unsigned int acct_num, mobile;
    int pin;
    float balance;
};

void balance_enquiry();
void balance_withdraw();
void balance_deposit();
void account_creation();
void account_modify();
void account_auth_id();
void account_auth_pin();

char data[] = {"ATM.dat"};
int main()
{
    int option;
    G:printf("\nWelcome To The ATM Services:\n");
    printf("\n****************************\n");
    printf("\nPlease Choose Your Options:\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n1. Banking Services:\n");
    printf("\n2. Account Creation:\n");
    printf("\n3. Account Modification:\n");
    scanf("%d", &option);
    switch (option)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            system("clear");
            int choice;
            account_auth_id();
            account_auth_pin();
            printf("\n********Welcome to ATM Service**************\n");
            printf("\n1. Check Balance\n");
            printf("\n2. Withdraw Cash\n");
            printf("\n3. Deposit Cash\n");
            printf("\n4. Quit\n");
            printf("\n******************?**************************?*\n\n");
            printf("\nEnter Your Choice: \n");
            scanf("%d", &choice);
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    balance_enquiry();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    balance_withdraw();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    balance_deposit();
                case 4:
                    printf("\nTHANK U FOR USING ATM \n");
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("\nINVALID CHOICE:\n");
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2:
            account_creation();
            break;
        case 3:
            account_modify();
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("\nTHANK U FOR USING ATM \n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("\nEnter Valid Choice:\n");
            break;
    }
    char transaction;
    printf("\nDO U WANT TO PERFORM ANOTHER TRANSCATION (y or n): \n");
    scanf(" %c", &transaction);
    if (transaction == 'y')
        goto G;
    printf("\nTHANKS FOR USING OUT ATM SERVICE:\n\n");
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void balance_enquiry()
{
    FILE *fp;
    struct user t;
    int id, f = 0;
    fp = fopen(data, "rb");
    printf("\nEnter Your ID Number:\n");
    D:scanf("%d", &id);
    while (1)
    {
        fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp);
        if (feof(fp))
            break;
        if (t.id == id)
        {
            f = 1;
            printf("Your Current Balance Is: %f\n", t.balance);
        }
        if (f == 0)
        {
            printf("Please Enter valid ID:\n");
            goto D;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void balance_withdraw()
{
    FILE *fp,*fp1;
    struct user t1;
    int withdraw,id, f = 0;
    fp = fopen("ATM.dat", "rb");
    fp1 = fopen("temp.dat", "wb");
    printf("\nEnter Your ID Number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &id);
    while (1)
    {
        fread(&t1, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp);
        if (feof(fp))
            break;
        if (t1.id == id)
        {
            f = 1;
            printf("\nENTER THE AMOUNT TO WITHDRAW: \n");
            A:scanf("%d", &withdraw);
            if (withdraw % 100 != 0)
            {
                printf("\nPLEASE ENTER THE AMOUNT IN MULTIPLES OF 100:\n");
                    goto A;
            }
            if (withdraw > t1.balance)
            {
                printf("\nINSUFFICENT BALANCE:\n");
                printf("\nTRY WITH LESSER AMOUNT\n");
                goto A;
                if (withdraw <= t1.balance)
                {
                    t1.balance = t1.balance - withdraw;
                    printf("\nPLEASE COLLECT CASH:\n\n");
                    printf("\nYOUR CURRENT BALANCE IS: %d", t1.balance);
                    fwrite(&t1, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp1);
                }
                else
                    fwrite(&t1, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp1);

            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
        fclose(fp1);
        if (f == 0)
        {
            printf("Sorry, There Is Some Technical Problem:\n\n");
        }
        else
        {
            fp = fopen("ATM.dat", "wb");
            fp1 = fopen("temp.dat", "rb");
            while (1)
            {
                fread(&t1, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp1);
                if (feof(fp1))
                    break;
                fwrite(&t1, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp);
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
        fclose(fp1);
    }
}

void balance_deposit()
{

}

void account_auth_id()
{
    FILE *fp;
    struct user t;
    int id, f = 0,k =0;
    fp = fopen(data, "rb");
    fflush(stdin);
    A:printf("\nEnter Your ID Number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &id);
    while (1)
    {
        fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp);
        if (feof(fp))
            break;
        if (t.id == id) 
        {
            f = 1;
            printf("Welcome, Mr %s\n", t.fname);
        }
        if (f == 0) 
        {
            k++;
            if(k == 3)
            {
                printf("You Have Reached Max. Attempts:\n");
                getch();
                return 0;
            }
            printf("You Have Entered Wrong ID:\n");
            printf("Please Enter Valid ID:\n");
            goto A;
        }
    }

}

void account_auth_pin()
{
    FILE *fp;
    struct user t;
    int tmpPin,k = 0, f = 0;
    fp = fopen(data, "rb");
    fflush(stdin);
    B:printf("Enter Your Secret Pin:\n");
    scanf("%d", &tmpPin);
    while (1)
    {
        fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp);
        if (feof(fp))
            break;
        if (t.pin == tmpPin)
        {
            f = 1;
            printf("Super!,Now You Can Enjoy Banking Services:\n");
        }
        if (f == 0)
        {
            k++;
            if(k == 3)
            {
                printf("You Have Entered Three Times Wrong PIN:\n");
                printf("Please,Try Again:\n");
                getch();
                return 0;
            }
            printf("You Have Entered Wrong PIN:\n");
            printf("Please Enter Correct PIN:\n");
            goto B;
        }
    }

}

void account_creation()
{
    FILE *fp;
    struct user t;
    fp = fopen(data, "ab");
    printf("Enter Your ID Number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &t.id);
    printf("\nEnter Your First Name:\n");
    scanf("%s", &t.fname);
    printf("\nEnter Your Last Name:\n");
    scanf("%s", &t.lname);
    printf("Enter Your New Account number:\n");
    scanf("%lu", &t.acct_num);
    printf("Enter Your Mobile Number:\n");
    scanf("%lu", &t.mobile);
    printf("Enter Your Secret PIN:\n");
    scanf("%d", &t.pin);
    printf("Enter The initial Amount To Deposit:\n");
    scanf("%f", &t.balance);
    fwrite(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}

void account_modify()
{

}
```

Comment: What is this: `G:printf("\nWelcome To The ATM Services:\n");`?

Comment: i have used goto G in the code if user want to do another transaction.

Comment: And `D:scanf` ... and more of those, what are they?

Comment: @AlexQuilliam it is a label, the target of a horrible `goto G;`

Comment: @RajeshDubey Very bad!!! First of all, a label must be clearly a label *syntaxwise* and second and most importantly DO NOT USE `goto` for that, it makes the code impossible to understand. That's why they created structured programs.

Comment: as i told i have used goto in the code to go back in the code

Comment: @RajeshDubey Using `goto` is bad practice, and should only be used very rarely, in select situations (e.g. breaking out of a double-for loop). [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/292/).

Comment: so what can i use if i want to go back in the code to perform task again

Comment: You will end up with spaghetti / rat's nest that nobody can follow - least of all yourself in six month's time. You need to structure the code properly.

Comment: should i use do while loop or any other method.please suggest me

Comment: @RajeshDubey Break your code up into multiple methods that only perform a few tasks at a time, and call the method that you need whenever you want to repeat something.

Comment: @Alex Quilliam ok i will do that

Comment: @RajeshDubey Adding to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431667/getting-error-while-reading-data-from-file-usinf-structure-in-c#comment83854705_48431667): use names that describe a single action, and then write a function that does exactly that action and nothing else. That way your code will be so easy to read, that bugs will appear very clear to you. Also, use comments where something is not immediately clear to the reader. Note, that when you write code you do so once, but you read it a lot, (*even your own code*).

Comment: @Iharob Al Asimi Yes you are right i have done coding like a maze.

Comment: learn to use your debugger

Comment: This is way too much code for us to deal with. Can you reduce the question to just the code that's related to the problem you're having? We don't need to see all the unrelated ATM functions.

Comment: Barmar: i think problem is in balance_enquiry and auth_id functions.

Comment: Never use floats for currency, use an integer for that.

Answer (score 0):

finally, my code is working properly..everything is fine now.
here is the my code for those who interested in this project or similar to this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct user
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
    char lname[20];
    int acct_num;
    int pin;
    int balance;
};
void balance_enquiry();
void balance_withdraw();
void balance_deposit();
void account_creation();
void account_modify();
void account_del();
void displayAll();

char fname[] = { "atm.dat" };

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        int ch;
        printf("\n\t\tWelcome To The ATM Services:\n");
        printf("\n\t\t****************************\n");
        printf("\n\t\tPlease Choose Your Options:\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("1. Balance Enquiry:\t\t4. Account creation:\n");
        printf("2. Withdraw Money:\t\t5. Account Modification:\n");
        printf("3. Deposit Money:\t\t6. Account Delete:\n\n");
        printf("\t\tPress 0 For Exit:\n");
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 1:
            balance_enquiry();
            break;
        case 2:
            balance_withdraw();
            break;
        case 3:
            balance_deposit();
            break;
        case 4:
            account_creation();
            break;
        case 5:
            account_modify();
            break;
        case 6:
            account_del();
            break;
        case 0:
            return 0;
        case 11://to see all details of customer in database.
            displayAll();
            break;
        default:
            printf("Enter Valid Options:\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void balance_enquiry()
{
    FILE *fp;
    struct user t;
    int id, tmpPin, found = 0;
    fp = fopen(fname, "rb");
    printf("\nEnter Your Customer ID:");
    scanf("%d", &id);
    printf("\nEnter Your Secret PIN:\n");
    scanf("%d", &tmpPin);
    while (1)
    {
        fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp);

        if (feof(fp))
        {
            break;
        }
        if (t.id == id && t.pin == tmpPin)
        {
            found = 1;
            printf("\n============================================\n\n");
            printf("Welcome, Mr %s %s\n\n", t.name, t.lname);
            printf("Account Number\t\t Balance\n\n");
            printf("%d\t\t %d\n\n", t.acct_num, t.balance);
            printf("==============================================\n\n");
        }
    }
    if (found == 0)
    {
        printf("\nSorry You Have Entered Wrong Details:\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
void balance_withdraw()
{
    FILE *fp, *fp1;
    struct user t;
    int id, found = 0;
    int withdraw, tmpPin;
    fp = fopen(fname, "rb");
    fp1 = fopen("temp.dat", "wb");

    printf("\nEnter the Customer ID:\n");
    scanf("%d", &id);
    printf("Enter Your Secret PIN:\n");
    scanf("%d", &tmpPin);
    while (1)
    {
        fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp);
        if (feof(fp))
        {
            break;
        }
        if (t.id == id && t.pin == tmpPin)
        {
            found = 1;
            do
            {
                do
                {
                    printf("\nEnter Amount To Withdraw:\n");
                    scanf("%d", &withdraw);
                    if (withdraw % 100 != 0)
                    {
                        printf("\nAmount Should Be Multiple Of 100:\n");
                    }
                } while (withdraw % 100 != 0);
                if (withdraw > t.balance)
                {
                    printf("\n Insufficient Balance:\n");
                    printf("\nTry With Lesser Amount\n");
                }
            } while (withdraw > t.balance);
            if (withdraw <= t.balance)
            {
                t.balance = t.balance - withdraw;
                printf("\nPlease Collect Your Cash:\n\n");
                printf("\nYour Current Balance Is: %d", t.balance);
                fflush(stdin);
                fwrite(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp1);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);
    if (found == 0)
    {
        printf("Sorry Try Again! Technical Problem:\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fp = fopen(fname, "wb");
        fp1 = fopen("temp.dat", "rb");
        while (1)
         {
            fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp1);
            if (feof(fp1))
            {
                break;
            }
            fwrite(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp);
        }

    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);
}
void balance_deposit()
{
    FILE *fp, *fp1;
    struct user t;
    int id, found = 0;
    int deposit, tmpPin;
    fp = fopen(fname, "rb");
    fp1 = fopen("temp.dat", "wb");

    printf("\nEnter the Customer ID:\n");
    scanf("%d", &id);
    printf("Enter Your Secret PIN:\n");
    scanf("%d", &tmpPin);
    while (1)
    {
        fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp);
        if (feof(fp))
        {
            break;
        }
        if (t.id == id && t.pin == tmpPin)
        {
            found = 1;
            do
            {
                printf("\nEnter Amount To Deposit:\n");
                scanf("%d", &deposit);
                if (deposit % 100 != 0)
                {
                    printf("\nPLEASE Enter The Amount In Multiples Of 100:\n");
                }
            } while (deposit % 100 != 0);
            t.balance = t.balance + deposit;
            printf("\nYOUR CURRENT BALANCE IS: %d", t.balance);
            fflush(stdin);
            fwrite(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp1);
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp1);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);
    if (found == 0)
    {
        printf("Sorry Try Again! Technical Problem:\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fp = fopen(fname, "wb");
        fp1 = fopen("temp.dat", "rb");

        while (1)
        {
            fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp1);
            if (feof(fp1))
            {
                break;
            }
            fwrite(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp);
        }

    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);
 }
void account_creation()
{
    FILE *fp;
    struct user t;
    fp = fopen(fname, "ab");
    printf("\t\tWelcome,First Time User\n\nPlease Enter Your Personal Details:\n\n");
    printf("Enter Customer ID Number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &t.id);
    printf("Enter You First Name:\n");
    scanf("%s", t.name);
    printf("Enter Your Last Name:\n");
    scanf("%s", t.lname);
    printf("Enter Your New Account Number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &t.acct_num);
    printf("Enter Your Secret PIN:\n");
    scanf("%d", &t.pin);
    printf("Enter The Initial Amount:\n");
    scanf("%d", &t.balance);
    fwrite(&t, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
void account_modify()
{
    FILE *fp, *fp1;
    struct user t;
    int id, found = 0;
    int tmpPin, ch;
    fp = fopen(fname, "rb");
    fp1 = fopen("temp.dat", "wb");
    printf("\nEnter the Customer ID you want to Modify:");
    scanf("%d", &id);
    printf("\nEnter the Secret PIN of Custmer ID = %d:\n", id);
    scanf("%d", &tmpPin);
    while (1)
    {
        fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp);

        if (feof(fp))
        {
            break;
        }
        if (t.id == id && t.pin == tmpPin)
        {
            found = 1;
            printf("Which Data You Want To Modify:\n");
            printf("\t1. Custormer ID:\n");
            printf("\t2. First Name:\n");
            printf("\t3. Last Name:\n");
            printf("\t4. Secret PIN:\n");
            printf("Others are Not Allowed:\n");
            scanf("%d", &ch);
            switch (ch)
            {
             case 1:
                printf("Enter New customer ID:");
                scanf("%d", &t.id);
                fflush(stdin);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Enter New Customer First Name:\n");
                scanf("%s", t.name);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Enter New Customer Last Name:\n");
                scanf("%s", t.lname);
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("Enter Your New Secret PIN:\n");
                scanf("%d", &t.pin);
                break;
            default:
                printf("tEnter Valid Choice:\n");
                break;
            }
            fwrite(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp1);
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp1);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);
    if (found == 0)
    {
        printf("Sorry No Record Found\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fp = fopen(fname, "wb");
        fp1 = fopen("temp.dat", "rb");
        while (1)
        {
            fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp1);
            if (feof(fp1))
            {
                break;
            }
            fwrite(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);
}

void account_del()
{
    FILE *fp, *fp1;
    struct user t;
    int id, found = 0;

    fp = fopen(fname, "rb");
    fp1 = fopen("temp.dat", "wb");

    printf("\nEnter the Customer ID you want to Delete:");
    scanf("%d", &id);
    while (1)
    {
        fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp);
        if (feof(fp))
        {
             break;
        }
        if (t.id == id)
        {
            found = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            fwrite(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp1);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);
    if (found == 0)
    {
        printf("Sorry No Record Found\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fp = fopen(fname, "wb");
        fp1 = fopen("temp.dat", "rb");
        while (1)
        {
            fread(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp1);
            if (feof(fp1))
            {
                break;
            }
            fwrite(&t, sizeof(t), 1, fp);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);
}
void displayAll()
{
    FILE *fp;
    struct user t;
    fp = fopen(fname, "rb");
    printf("\n========================================================\n\n");
    printf("\t\t All Customer Details\n\n");
    printf("=====================================================\n\n");
    printf("ID\tFirst\tLast\tAccount Number\tPIN\tBalance\n\n");
    while (1)
    {
        fread(&t, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp);
        if (feof(fp))
        {
            break;
        }
        printf("%d\t", t.id);
        printf("%s\t", t.name);
        printf("%s\t", t.lname);
        printf("%d\t", t.acct_num);
        printf("%d\t", t.pin);
        printf("%d\t\n\n", t.balance);
    }
    printf("=====================================================\n\n");
    fclose(fp);
}
```